# Slanted bitmap, stride calculation for RGB565 C#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, bitmap, stride

Some of my resulting images are slanted, some are not.

Expected Result: (529x22)

[image]

Actual Result: (529x22)

> Don't mind the different image sizes, these are screenshots. They are both 529x22.

[image]

The code I am using, I just got this from an answer on a question here at SO.

```
// some other method
byte[] pixels = new byte[size - 16];
Array.Copy(this.data, offset, pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
this.ByteToImage(w, h, pixels);

// builds the pixels to a image
private Bitmap ByteToImage(int w, int h, byte[] pixels)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);

    var BoundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(BoundsRect,
                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                    bmp.PixelFormat);

    // bytes => not using this because it gives error
    // eg. pixel.Length = 16032, bytes = 16064
    int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;

    Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, bmpData.Scan0, pixels.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return bmp;
}
```

I'm confused because some works ok, not slanted. But others are slanted. What did I miss?

### Update

As stated in the comments and answers, the problem is how I'm calculating stride. I'm still confused on how to do it but I tried this:

```
public static void RemovePadding(this Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;

    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var pixels = new byte[bitmapData.Width * bitmapData.Height * bytesPerPixel];

    for (int row = 0; row < bitmapData.Height; row++)
    {
        var dataBeginPointer = IntPtr.Add(bitmapData.Scan0, row * bitmapData.Stride);
        Marshal.Copy(dataBeginPointer, pixels, row * bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel, bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel);
    }

    Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixels.Length);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}
```

But the result is (more slanted):

[image]

Comment: You clearly have a stride issue. If you want help fixing your mistake, post a question with a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and be more specific about what errors, if any, occur when running the code. Likely you are simply computing the stride incorrectly; some images work because they have a width compatible with your incorrect calculation (stride in the Windows bitmap format is rounded to the nearest 32 bits...maybe it's only 16, I don't recall for certain off the top of my head).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what it was called. New to bitmaps. I'll try to fix the question.

Comment: @TaW 4 bytes? the padding?

Comment: Yes or rather: a scanline is padded to the next multiple of four byte, ie the [stride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is 0-3 bytes longer than the net pixel line.

Comment: You don't have to calculate Stride nor to remove padding, the system calculates Stride and inserts the padding. Most likely the way you move unpadded data __in one go__ is the error.. A __loop__ going over the lines seems more likely to work.

Comment: @TaW what am i missing? im new to c#. And in python i never had problems like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121418/discussion-between-taw-and-majidarif).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work here:

```
private Bitmap ByteToImage(int w, int h, byte[] pixels)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);
    byte bpp = 2;
    var BoundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(BoundsRect,
                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                    bmp.PixelFormat);
    // copy line by line:
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++ )
        Marshal.Copy(pixels, y * w * bpp, bmpData.Scan0 + bmpData.Stride * y, w * bpp);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return bmp;
}
```

I use a loop to place each row of data at the right spot. The data do not include the padding, but the target address must do so.

Therefore we need to multiply the **data access** by the actual `width * bytePerPixel` but the **target adress** by the [`Stride`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), i.e. the length of the scanline, padded to the next multiple of four bytes. For `width=300` it is `stride=300`, for `width=301` it is `stride=304`..

Moving all pixel data in one step can only work when there is no padding, i.e.  when the width is a multiple of `4`.

Answer (score 1):

This expects the stride to correspond to the width, without padding. There can be padding. The padding would "eat" some of the next line, which will therefore appear to shift left.

Since the padding breaks up the lines, the only real way to deal with it (other than using the same padding everywhere) is copying line by line. You can calculate the starting address of a line with `bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride`. Copy starting there, for every `y`.

> // bytes => not using this because it gives error

Yes, because your array does not have padding. So you were telling it to copy more data than the array held.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by copying line by line. Can you provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: @majidarif row by row then, however you want to call it. The point is, the padding exists just past the right side of the image, so you could say there are virtual pixels there. They should be skipped, otherwise part of the image is lost in there.

Comment: Does that mean I need to create a new byte array and copy `pixels` there, skipping the padding?

Comment: You could do that, but I meant copying it chunk by chunk directly into the bitmap. Using a temporary array as an extra step isn't necessary.

Comment: I tried what you said, but still couldn't make it work.